# Single webstore with multiple fullfilment locations

Tags: shipping, multistore, inventory

I have a store franchise who want a single web presence for their stores but want the orders to be sent to a local fulfilment location for postage. There are multiple fulfilment locations across the country, and these can be identified by the delivery address. How can the Magento framework be utilised so that the agents doing fulfilment at each site can access a list of orders that they can action?

I have heard that multi-site is an option, but this appears to set up multiple websites via domain or subdirectory and is designed for different product sets, languages or locations. So it appears that this does not meet the brief.

Comment: @marius Are you able to give some advice on how to make the question more appropriate? That is the requirement I need to fulfil and if there are multiple ways to do that I do not know about them.

Comment: First of all you need to explain what everything means in your question. One example is " local shopfronts for postage". Second, don't ask questions like "Here is what my client requested, can you do that for me?". Third, explain what have you tried and where did you hit a brick wall. And last but not least read this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Marius are you able to reopen the Question? I have adjusted the question to better suit the standards.